# Custom markers using Python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I would like to know how I can generate the marker for the black colored line shown in this picture. (Source: NCEP & NOAA)
It's the marker for a storm or hurricane in standard weather maps.

[image]

I can probably generate an image file of the marker symbol. But, I am not aware of how I can tell matplotlib to use the image as a marker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The marker looks like a `6`. If this is the case, you can use a `6` as a marker as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [2,3,1,4]

plt.scatter(x,y, s= 100,marker="$6$")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If this is not an option, you may define your custom marker using a path. To this end, the coordinates of the path need to be known. I have invented some values below, maybe they already suit the needs here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath

def get_hurricane():
    u = np.array([  [2.444,7.553],
                    [0.513,7.046],
                    [-1.243,5.433],
                    [-2.353,2.975],
                    [-2.578,0.092],
                    [-2.075,-1.795],
                    [-0.336,-2.870],
                    [2.609,-2.016]  ])
    u[:,0] -= 0.098
    codes = [1] + [2]*(len(u)-2) + [2] 
    u = np.append(u, -u[::-1], axis=0)
    codes += codes

    return mpath.Path(3*u, codes, closed=False)

hurricane = get_hurricane()
plt.scatter([1,1,2],[1.4,2.3,2.8], s=350, marker=hurricane, 
            edgecolors="crimson", facecolors='none', linewidth=2)
plt.scatter([0,1,2],[1,3,1], s=150, marker=hurricane, 
            edgecolors="k", facecolors='none')
plt.scatter([0,1.8,3],[0,2,4], s=150, marker="o", 
            edgecolors="k", facecolors='none')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The marker is used to denote a hurricane. It is a specific symbol. I doubt the symbol suggested works.

Comment: Where can we find information about that symbol? If you want help creating a marker you must somehow define how that marker needs to look.

Comment: Sorry about that. The 2nd and 3rd symbol in [this image](http://www.opc.ncep.noaa.gov/product_description/ITCZ.jpg) is what I would like to arrive at.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I would be glad if you could explain how you arrived at the symbol. Also, what you have done is for a tropical storm. For a tropical cyclone, the circular region inside the tropical storm symbol needs to be filled. Is that possible as well?

Comment: The solution shows how to arrive at a custom marker using pairs of coordinates. It uses some values to get half of the symbol and then mirrors them to get the complete symbol. You could fill the symbol (e.g. facecolor=red) but that would not look good. Instead you can use a second scatter witch provides the filled part. Either in the same way  the first one works supplying coordinates or simply using a circle as marker.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I was able to fill color inside the marker with a scatter like you mentioned. However, I still don't seem to understand the math behind the function you have defined to create the marker itself. It would be great if you could explain how you got to finding the coordinates for the curve and why you are returning two values (3*u and codes).

Comment: I invented some points to define a half-spiral. Then moved that half spiral, such that its mirror point is the origin (move by 0.098 in xdirection). A path in matplotlib consists of two parts the coordinates and the codes. A code of 1 means "move to" and a code of 2 means "line to". The factor 3 in the coordinates is to make the symbol the same size as a round marker. Of course you can directly hardcode the value 0.098 and the factor 3 into the coordinates if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I understand it so much better now!