# metpy: is there a hurricane marker?

Tags: matplotlib, metpy

I see metpy has some meteorological symbols in https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/blob/master/metpy/plots/wx_symbols.py
and shown in the gallery here https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/plots/Station_Plot.html#sphx-glr-examples-plots-station-plot-py

I'm curious if there is tropical storm and hurricane marker like the ones given here: http://www.e-missions.net/wvstorm/?cat=2&sid=1&pid=35&page=Weather%20Symbols%20Reference%20Guide

Not sure if the solution is a custom marker as discussed here: [Custom markers using Python (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726675/custom-markers-using-python-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no hurricane symbol in MetPy. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/226) to add it though.